# RegEx expression that will match string of a particular format

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I have a line with `ORDER BY DESC(?year)` where `?year` can be anything followed by a question mark `(?)` such as ?name, ?address etc. I have tried `ORDER BY DESC\(\?[a-z]+\)` to capture the whole string as `ORDER BY DESC(?year)` but not working.

lex file:

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "grammar.tab.h"
%}

%option case-insensitive

%%
[1-9][0-9]*         { yylval.i = atoi(yytext); return INT_NUM; }
"ORDER BY DESC\(\?[a-z]+\)"     { yylval.s = strdup(yytext); return ORDER_BY_DESC; }            
"\n"                { yylineno++; }
\.                  { return DOT; }             
[ \t]+              { /* ignore white space */ }                                                                                                            
"#".*               { /* ignore comments */ }
[ \t\v\f\r]+            { }
.               { std::cerr << "Lexical Error!\n"; }        
%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

bison file:

```
    %{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <regex>

    using namespace std;

    extern int yylineno;
    extern int yylex();

    void yyerror(char *s, ...);
    %}

    %error-verbose

    %union
    {
        int i;
        char *s;
    }
    %token<i> INT_NUM;
    %token<s> ORDER_BY_DESC;

    %%
    order_by:
            | ORDER_BY_DESC
            {
                   string s($<s>1); 
                   string str = s.substr(0, s.size() - 1);
                   char *x = new char[str.length() + 1];
                   order_by_stmt = str;
                   strcpy(x, str.c_str());
                   $<s>$ = x;
            }
        ;

    %%

    void yyerror(char *s, ...) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, s);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: error: ", yylineno);
        vfprintf(stderr, s, ap);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }


int main() {

    yyparse();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What tool you used? There are differences in some implementations of RegExp.

Comment: I am using regex for Flex.

Comment: ActionScript? Show me the code.

Comment: In lex file ' "ORDER BY DESC\(\?[a-z]+\)"     { yylval.s = strdup(yytext); return ORDER_BY_DESC; }' and in bison file 'order_by:
        | ORDER_BY_DESC
        {
               string s($<s>1); 
               string str = s.substr(0, s.size() - 1);
               char *x = new char[str.length() + 1];
               strcpy(x, str.c_str());
               $<s>$ = x;
        }'

Comment: Errr, can you put the code in the question?

Comment: I have attached only the required portion of my code.

Comment: Try "ORDER BY DESC\\(\\?[a-z]+\\)"    You want the '\' character to be recognized by the regular expression grammar. Right now, the c language is replacing "\(" with who-knows-what, and "\?" becomes simply "?".

Comment: I am using "ORDER BY DESC"\([^)]*\) to get the output. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"ORDER BY DESC"([^)]*) could be a solution for this question.
```